# How to convert a React JS functional component to a class component?

Tags: reactjs

Hi I have this `reactjs` snippet I need to convert this to a `class` component (now it is a functional` component)

But this has to be carried out carefully since I try to get values from `Form` component to the `Main` component and prints that value within the `Main` component.

This is my `Main.jsx`

```
function Main(props) {
   
   const [firstName, setFirstName] = React.useState('');

   return (
     <div>
       <Form setFirstName={setFirstName} firstName={firstName} />
       <p> {firstName} <p/> // this works fine
     </div>
   );
}
```

And this is the `Form.jsx` I need this to write as a `class` component instead of a `functional component` which is it now.

```
function Form({ firstName, setFirstName }) {

   const handleChange = (event) => {
      setFirstName(event.target.value)
   }
   
   return (
     <div>
       <TextField onChange={handleChange} value={firstName} />
     </div>
   );
}
```

I tried to convert this like this, but then it doesn't print the value of `firstName` inside

```
export default class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: "",
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.props.firstName = event.target.value;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.firstName} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
<p> {firstName} <p/> // and now this wouldn'tt work after converting this to a class component
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't understand why you'd want to convert this to a class at all, but I'll assume that you have a good reason.

**Do not** re-assign props like this: `this.props.firstName = event.target.value;`. Data flow in React goes one direction. Top -> down. If you need to update a prop, you pass a separate prop that is a function to update the first's value (see docs on [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)).

If you are wanting to move the state to the `Form` component, just update state like this:

```js
handleChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({ firstName: event.target.value });
};
```

But notice this will not update props, so this is probably not what you're looking for.

To be more similar to your functional component setup, don't use state at all in `Form` and keep it in `Main` like it was before. This means we can cut out the constructor as well.

```js
export default class Form extends Component {
  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.props.setFirstName(event.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.props.firstName} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Here it gives an error for the `this.state.firstName` inside `TextField` in class component.

Comment: @user13456401 that was a typo, it is fixed now.

Comment: Okay, this is working. Thank you so much. Is it possible to use a constructor with props as in usual way inside the newly converted class component?

Comment: Sure it's possible, its just not necessary with the current requirements.